# Can shift a component's function in some other file in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have multiple functions in my vue component like this. Is there any way i can shift functions in some other file and then import those here . This is my `App.vue`

```
  getLocation: async function () {
   
    },
    subscribe: function (longitude, latitude) {


    },

    async openLocationWarning() {

     
    },
    uploadData(data, key) {
    
    },
    downloadData()
    {
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant but you can use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). You can also store it in a js file and export it.

```
export yourFunction() {

}

export anotherFunction(){
}
```

And import it in your file

```
import {yourFunction, anotherFunction} from 'path/to/your_file';

methods: {
  callSomeFunction() {
    // you can call it like this.
    yourFunction();
  }
}
```